# Is it possible to detect arrow key while user types a command in powershell command line?

Tags: powershell

For example let's say I have an increment command

```
 increment 10
```

Before even validating if user use arrow key up, it would show

```
 increment 11
```

I don't think it's possible but maybe I'm happily wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Try like this:

```
$keycode = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
```

It returns a keycode inside assigned variable.

37 = left
38 = up
39 = right
40 = down